# align checkbox with label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in bootstrap. I need to align the label with the checkbox but even after looking at some solutions, I have not been successful:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>
      Show entities?
      <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 6px 0 0;" id="inactiveEnt" name="checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>           
  <div class="col-md-8" id="isactiveTxt">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Note: "-" inactive</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version you're using ?

Comment: have a look in input-groups

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap, just use a form-group. Create the label and reference the input by using a "for" attribute that matches the ID of the input.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="myInput" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Input Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="myInput" placeholder="Input Here">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want I think this can be the solution you are looking for (append classes btn and btn-default to your input element to align vertically to your label text)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-default">
    </span>
    <label class="form-label">here is my label</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p9wud84v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet hope it will help :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="d-flex align-items-center"> Show entities? <input type="checkbox"  id="inactiveEnt" name="checkbox" class="ml-3"> </label>
  </div>           
  <div class="col-md-8" id="isactiveTxt">
    <span style="font-weight:bold">Note: "-" inactive</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering if you are using bootstrap 4, you can do this to get that result

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Show entities?</label>
</div>

<!-- or using inline form -->

<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
    Show entities?
  </label>
</div>
```